# Are the coordinates of $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ the same in all bases of $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Are the coordinates of $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ the same in all bases of $\mathbb{R^n}$?

That is,

Given $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any basis $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then
is $$x_E=x$$

(where $x_E$ is the "representation of $x$ in basis $E$", i.e. $x_E=C^{-1}x_\epsilon$,
where $C=Mat(id,F,\epsilon)$, a change of basis matrix. $\epsilon$ is the std basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$)

Comment: Why would you think so? Did you try taking $n = 2$ and experimenting with two different bases?

Comment: The vectors are the same, but the coordinates used to describe it differ. Changing basis is really just warping the reference grid you put underneath the vector to help you use algebra.

Comment: Yeah well I think the confusion comes from "the vector is the same, but the coordinates are different".

Answer (score 1):

No; the point about using different bases is that the coordinate representations of the vectors change. Take for example $\mathbb{R}$ with the bases $E = (1)$ and $F = (2)$. Then $x_E = x$ and $x_F = x/2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.